# Oracle PL/SQL SUBSTR error

Tags: plsql, substr

i need to convert a varchar to an array using pl/sql, but when i use the SUBSTR function, i get this error:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

this is my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_string varchar2(20) := 'hello';
  type array_string is varray(5) of varchar2(10);
  v_length number;
  cnt number;
  v_char char(1);
BEGIN
  v_length := length(v_string);
  while (cnt < v_length)
  loop
    v_char := SUBSTR(v_string, cnt, 1);
    array_string(cnt) := v_char;
    cnt := cnt + 1;
  end loop;
END;
```

when i (partially) type 'SUBSTR' it autocompletes to SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 64) so it should know the command, right?

what am i doing wrong? im pretty new at pl/sql

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize variable `cnt` before using it in `substr`.
You must use variable name instead of type name in `array_string(cnt)`.
You must `extend` your varray before writing new value to it.

Comment: Thanks! that worked for as far as i got another error with the substr, so i'm not all there, but on the way! This is now my code:

edit: maybe i should put the code in an answer here, so you can oversee it better
new error:
Subscript outside of limit

Comment: `cnt` must be initialized with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle environment, the starting index for varrays is always 1.

Your `cnt` is starting from 0. So the during the first time execution of the loop, the

```
a_string(cnt) := v_char;
```

cnt is 0.

Initialize cnt as 1, and run the loop for

```
while (cnt < 5)
```

This will remove the error you are getting